# Replacing multiple char from String with single space

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I want to replace multiple character in given string with a single space.

eg:  `He is a very very good boy, isn't he?`
     Should be replaced to

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

My code is

```
String str = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?"
String str2 = str.replaceAll("![,?.\_'@+] +"," ");
 String []tokens = str2.split(" +");

for(int i = 0; i< tokens.length; i++)
       System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

But the output is

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy,
isn't
he?
```

Please correct my code if possible or suggest a new one.

Comment: If you are trying to splt the text into words, then you should NOT split `"isn't"` into `"isn" "t"`.  The apostrophe is part of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the above but this one worked.

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String S = br.readLine();
List<String> splitted = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(S.split("[ :#$%^&/<>{}*|;_()!,?.'@+\\\\\\[\\]\\\"]+")));
splitted.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
System.out.println(splitted.size());
for (String word: splitted) System.out.println(word);
```

this is solution for the whole problem which I have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great article: [Replace All Method](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-strip-characters-string-letters-numbers-replace)

If you want to only have letters in your string, and replace everything else with a space, here is the statement:

```
str2 = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", " ");
```

If you want to replace the characters you mentioned (excluding brackets), use this:

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^[!,?._'@+]]", " ");
```

If you want to include the brackets, use this:

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^[!,?._'@+\\[\\]]]", " ");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Space or any of the special characters like ![,?.\_'@+] will act as a delimiter. Rest all characters are allowed.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the [] brackets too?

Comment: Using s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^[!,?._'@+]]", " "); will remove the characters that are inside the brackets, and s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^[!,?._'@+\\\[\\\]]]", " "); will remove square brackets as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your regular expression is missing an escape.  I think you wanted to include the back slash `\` in your expression, but you have to escape it like this: `\\`.

Moreover, your regular expression `"![,?.\_'@+] +"` indicates that you want to replace a combination of an exclamation mark `!`, any character that is part of the set containing `,`, `?`, `.`, `\`, `_`, `'`, `@`, and `+`, and one or more spaces (`+`) by a single space.

The regular expression `[,'?]+` should do the job.  You can read more about how to form the correct expression at [Regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only with alphabets then

```
String x = sequence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z] +"," ");
```

and with alphabet and digits

```
String y = sequence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9] +"," ");
```

Have a look at [Replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) and [ReplaceAll()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) methods

Comment: Space or any of the special characters like ![,?.\_'@+] will act as a delimiter. Rest all characters are allowed.